# Hadoop Pig Latin Tuples: How to pass them to UDFs?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My goal is to pass every field in the input to a UDF as follows:

```
A = LOAD './input/file1' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (f1:chararray, f2:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE com.mycompany.udf.FAKEUDF(tuple(*));
```

**NOTE**:  I am using Cloudera's version 0.12.0-cdh5.0.0.
The above `FOREACH` is just one of my many attempts. I have seen examples like

```
...FAKEUDF(*)
```

And so forth.

The main question is, what is the correct syntax? And has the syntax changed from earlier versions?

Here is a link which shows the lone asterisk syntax:

[Chapter 10: Writing Evaluation & Filter Functions](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch10.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends how u are processing your reqiurement. Argument will be name of column (one or more) like FAKEUDF(column1,column2,....) or  for all the column you can specify * also like FAKEUDF(*)  or you can specify relationName also. In UDF, you have to take out the column values from the tuple like : tuple.get(index). You have to be careful what you have sent as argument based on that processing is happening. It can be even DataBag.

Comment: I found that I needed the curly brackets between the parens -- naked asterisk did not work for me: I did not get wrong values but rather Pig complained about the syntax.

Comment: {} (curly braces) is for bag data type. If {*} is working for you then you were processing it as Bag in UDF. It will be more clear if i would see the UDF.